# RCTView generated view config for bubblingEventTypes does not match native, missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

RCTView generated view config for bubblingEventTypes does not match native, missing: topPointerOver topPointerLeave topPointerMove topPointerEnter topPointerUp topPointerDown topPointerOut topPointerCancel

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example using https://snack.expo.dev/ , or provide the code that you think is causing the error.